# Thunar stopped working

Tags: ubuntu-mate, thunar

Thunar has stopped working. I tried re-installing it.

What can I check?

```
andy@7_~/Downloads$ thunar /media/storagedrive/Ubuntu_Mate_18.04


Failed to register: Timeout was reached
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, but Thunar uses Gio for remote shares and devices.
If you have a bookmark referencing a Samba or NFS share and that is not present, or you are trying to access a remote drive, Thunar might get an timeout from gio.
You could work around it by changing the group's read/write permissions of the "external" disk or share. (use `chmod g+rw`for this)

A (temporary) alternative would be to change the `AutoMount` entry in `/usr/share/gvfs/mounts/network.mount`into **false**. But that would only make sense if the problem is a network problem - that should be fixed in `etc/fstab` or the systemd mount points.

Comment: Thunar started working again after a reboot.